# Sum of order statistics

Tags: summation, order-statistics

Is there a general expression for the pdf of the sum of the order statistics? Suppose they are all drawn independently from the same distribution.

Comment: Are you looking for sums of all the ordered statistics or only some of them?

Comment: All of them. More precisely, I have N-1 draws and I want the distribution of the sum of these N-1 draws.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The sum of order statistics of $n$ random variables is equal to the sum of the $n$ random variables. So if the random variables are independent, the distribution of $n$ random variables is given by convolution of the pdf's of these random variables. You might want to check [this](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~susan/courses/s116/node114.html) out and some articles on how to find the pdf of sum of two independent random variables.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. For example, I can use this property to show that the expected value of the sum of n order statistics equals n times the expected value. But i do not see how this would help me in getting the distribution of the sum.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is indeed what I suspected/feared...it's gonna be nasty.
Btw, any hint on how to calculate the same thing, but conditional on the highest one being less (or equal than) some threshold a?
That is, how can I get the distribution of the sum of the n order statistics conditional on the highest of them not exceeding a?

Comment: I would suggest you search Math.SE for this and if you don't find a satisfactory hint/answer, ask a separate question. But yes, there are tactics for those.